# How to retain column readonly state; if datagridview readonly state changes in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm developing a windows form application, in which I'm using a datagridview. It  has some columns where ReadOnly is true and some where ReadOnly is false.

At a certain point, I have to prevent user to edit the datagridview, but still view all rows, so I set datagridview's ReadOnly property to true.

And when the datagridview's readonly state is set back to false, all columns' ReadOnly property is set to false as well.

I Can't disable the datagridview because in disabled state the user can't view all rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original idea was to have you create a list of the `ReadOnly` columns for each `DataGridView`. Then have you reset those columns from that list, either in the `ReadOnlyChanged` event for each `DataGridView` (too much code copy), or send those lists as a second parameter to the *common code* method and reset them there.  But then I thought, *what if you only have access to the Common Code*?

This led me to the following generic solution.  The idea remains the same: each `DataGridView` will have a list of `ReadOnly` columns.  But this list will be directly attached to the `DataGridView` via the `Tag` property instead of as code bloat in the dgv's (perhaps unreachable) parent class.

If your *common code* method looks something like this:

```
public void DoStuff(DataGridView dgv)
{
    if (dgv.ReadOnly)
    {
        dgv.ReadOnly = false;
        // Do related stuff.
    }
    else
    {
        dgv.ReadOnly = true;
        // Do other related stuff.
    }

    // Do common stuff.
}
```

Make these changes to *Save* / *Load* the `ReadOnly` columns:

```
public void DoStuff(DataGridView dgv)
{
    if (dgv.ReadOnly)
    {
        dgv.ReadOnly = false;

        // Load the saved ReadOnly columns.
        List<DataGridViewColumn> rocs = dgv.Tag as List<DataGridViewColumn>;

        if (rocs != null)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn roc in rocs)
            {
                roc.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        // Do related stuff.
    }
    else
    {
        // Save the ReadOnly columns before the DGV ReadOnly changes.
        List<DataGridViewColumn> rocs = new List<DataGridViewColumn>();

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ReadOnly)
            {
                rocs.Add(col);
            }
        }

        dgv.Tag = rocs;
        dgv.ReadOnly = true;

        // Do other related stuff.
    }

    // Do common stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not revert the `Column.ReadOnly` state by just setting `DataGridView.ReadOnly`

You can save the ReadOnly columns into a List first and use a loop

```
foreach(var column in dgv.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Where(i => !ReadOnlyColumnList.Contains(i)))
{
    column.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm changing Readonly state in common code; and passing multiple datagridview.

Comment: @PravinChopade Are the *common code* and the multiple `DataGridView` controls contained in the same class?  If no, then are the `DataGridView` controls all coming from the same class?  If yes, I assume  your common class has a pseudo call similar to this `public void DoStuff(list of DataGridViews) { set each DataGridView.ReadOnly to true; // do stuff }`.  If no, I assume this call `public void DoStuff(a single DataGridView) { set the DataGridView.ReadOnly to true; // do stuff }` which is called from each class for each DGV.  Can you clarify?

Comment: the second one, passing single datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [CellBeginEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit?view=net-5.0) event, and check if the column is any of my read only columns, then cancel the event.

```
private void dataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
  //ReadOnly off/on enables this again - force non-editable
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 5) e.Cancel = true;
}
```